# i can't install react using npx create-react-app myfirstreactapp

Tags: reactjs, node.js, create-react-app

after running the create react app command, this is the output.

```
C:\Users\Izora\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js:3
const {stdout: stdoutColor, stderr: stderrColor} = require('supports-color');
                                                   ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\Izora\node_modules\supports-color\index.js from C:\Users\Izora\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js not supported. 
Instead change the require of C:\Users\Izora\node_modules\supports-color\index.js in C:\Users\Izora\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Izora\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js:3:52) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

Node.js v20.10.0
```

I then try to install the supports-color module but it happens al over again

```
PS C:\Users\Izora\Documents\react> npm install supports-color -g

changed 1 package in 3s

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
PS C:\Users\Izora\Documents\react> npx create-react-app myfirstreactapp
C:\Users\Izora\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js:3
const {stdout: stdoutColor, stderr: stderrColor} = require('supports-color');
                                                   ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\Izora\node_modules\supports-color\index.js from C:\Users\Izora\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of C:\Users\Izora\node_modules\supports-color\index.js in C:\Users\Izora\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Izora\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js:3:52) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

Node.js v20.10.0
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer but Create React App [isn't officially recommended any more](https://github.com/reactjs/react.dev/pull/5487#issuecomment-1409720741). Try [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) instead... `npm create vite@latest my-react-app -- --template react`

Comment: another error pops up

'vite' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

when i follow the vite installation process

Comment: What docs are you looking at? I can't see any that say to run `vite`. After you run the `create` command, you use `cd my-react-app`, `npm install` then `npm run dev`. It should have given you those instructions when you created your project

Comment: i tried but it still doesn't work. it gives me the same error 
i followed the docs from their official website and the app folder is already created. with the app.jsx, index.html and all. when it comes to running with npm run dev, this error shows up


PS C:\Users\Izora\Documents\my-react-app> npm run dev

> my-react-app@0.0.0 dev
> vite

'vite' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file

Comment: Did you run `npm install` before `npm run dev`? Could you please [edit] your question to detail exactly what steps you've taken and what the output / result was of each?

Comment: Please also include the generated `package.json` file

Comment: i have asked it in a newer question with the packet.json file content in it, couldn't edit this one sufficiently